# Disable bluetooth when not in use, automatically

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I already automated Bluetooth turning off when the lid is closed using `blueutil` and `sleepwatcher`.

Now I would bring this a step further and automatically disable Bluetooth after it has been idle for one minute without any active connection.

How can I do that on a MBP 2019?

Comment: What's the motivation for this? It seems pretty disruptive to toggle it with an idle time of 1 min. What do you have connected with bluetooth?

Comment: @AshZade When no devices are connected for a while, I see no reason to keep it on, but shall forget to turn it off. It conserves energy and protects privacy to avoid using bluetooth when it's not needed. Occasionally, I connect a wireless headset or a mouse to it.

Comment: The energy consumption is so negligible, I don't think you'd notice, for example:

"When Bluetooth has an active paired connection to a hands-free device it consumes 2.5 mw. As the battery capacity of an iPhone 8 (not plus) is about 6900 mwh, if Bluetooth was the only thing using power the battery would run down in about 2800 hours, or about 3 months."

For privacy, you can create a shortcut that disables it and trigger it however you like, but I cannot see a way to detect if it's not in use.